# Initializing first C# class object in second class list

Tags: c#

I am seeking a better and correct way of initializing Objects which is listed in another object? For example let's say I have two Classes `Player` and `Team` and one of properties in the `Team` class is a generic list of `Player` as

```
public List<Player>  Players{ get; set; }
```

How I can Initialize the `Player` inside initializing the `Team`? I mean let's assume I do not have any object for `Player` and want to created them while creating/initializing the `Team` class object

```
void Main()
{

}

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Player(){
        Name  = string.Empty;
    }
}

public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<Player>  Players{ get; set; } 
    public Team(){
        Name = string.Empty;
        Players = new List<Player>();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about passing an `IEnumerable<Player>` to the `Team()` constructor that it can use to populate the list?

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize your variable in the constructor:

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; } 

    public Team()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
        Players = new List<Player>()
        {
            new Player() { Name = "A"},
            new Player() { Name = "B"},
            new Player() { Name = "C"}
        };
    }
}
```

Or you can use a language feature from C# 6.0 called auto-property initializers:

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; } = new List<Player>()
    {
        new Player() { Name = "A"},
        new Player() { Name = "B"},
        new Player() { Name = "C"}
    };
}
```

The difference is only in the syntax. Both ways will result in the same program being executed.

Comment: Thanks Eiver, but where exactly is this happening? in `Team` constructor? or in `Team` Property declaration?

Comment: You can do it either way. I updated my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just mean this:

```
public Team(){
    Name = string.Empty;
    Players = new List<Player> {
        new Player(), new Player() //etc
   };
}
```

if you had a list of names for each player you could pass them into the Team constructor (or create an overload) as follows:

```
public Team(IEnumerable<string> playerNames){
    Name = string.Empty;
    Players = new List<Player>();
    foreach(var player in playerNames {
        Players.Add(new Player { Name = player});
   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Tim but are the `Player()` constructor of `Player` ? in that case why not using the `Name` Property?

Comment: you'd have to set the names to something, do you have a list of names for each player?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you have, an instantiated `Team` has an empty list of players. To add a player to that list, simply add an instantiated `Player` to the list, just like you would do for any `List<T>`.

```
var myTeam = new Team();
var myPlayer = new Player();

myTeam.Players.Add(myPlayer);
```

If you want to do this during the initialization of the `Team`, the same approach applies:

```
public class Team
{
    // ...

    public Team()
    {
        Players = new List<Player>();

        this.Players.Add(new Player());
        this.Players.Add(new Player());
    }
}
```

You can also do this in one line:

```
public class Team
{
    // ...

    public Team()
    {
        Players = new List<Player>() 
        { 
            new Player(), 
            new Player() 
        };
    }
}
```

Presumably, you would want to receive these players via a constructor parameter? If so, then add the constructor parameter instead of directly instantiating new players:

```
public class Team
{
    // ...

    public Team(IEnumerable<Player> players)
    {
        Players = new List<Player>(players);
    }
}
```

Note that this code makes a new list (with the same objects in it), rather than using the collection object that was passed into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inialize Players while initializing the team, you can just take a List of Players as the parameter for Team's constructor, like this:

```
    public Team(List<Player> players)
    {
        Players = players;
    }
```

and then call it this way:

```
var team = new Team(new List<Player>() { new Player("name1"), new Player("name2") });
```

You might as well take a more **abstract collection as Type** for constructor parameter, like `IEnumerable`, this will allow you to pass other collections at initialization:

```
    public Team(IEnumerable<Player> players)
    {
        Players = players;
    }
```

The final code would look like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var team = new Team("Juventus",
            new List<Player>
            {
                new Player("Ronaldo"), 
                new Player("Messi")
            });
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Player(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public Team(string name, IEnumerable<Player> players)
    {
        Name = name;
        Players = players;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're passing `Players` in and then ignoring it - also coding convention is the parameter should be `players`

Comment: Just a typo, my bad

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that you want to have a default list of players initialized already in every Team ojbect, you clould use this syntax:

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; set; } = new List<Player>();
}
```